# Android 2.3.6 issue

Tags: mediaelement.js

I made a simple UL list: clicking on the <li> element it switches the video played by the mediaelementplayer.
Works fine in desktop browsers, but with Android 2.3.6 it always plays the first video no matter on which <li> element you click. ( I tried with a Samsung Galaxy S II, but works well with Samsung Galaxy S III and Android 4.0.4)

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<video id="playervideo" width="488" height="286" class="mejs-wmp">
<source src="uploads/media/video/first.mp4">
</video>

<ul>
<li><span id="first" class="current">First</span></li>
<li><span id="second">Second</span></li>
<li><span id="third">Third</span></li>
</ul>




<script>
new MediaElementPlayer('#playervideo', {
features: ['playpause','progress','duration','volume'],
success: function(media, node, player)
 {

$("ul li span#first").click(function () {
media.pause();
media.setSrc('uploads/media/video/first.mp4');
media.play();
$("ul li span").removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");
});

$("ul li span#second").click(function () {
media.pause();
media.setSrc('uploads/media/video/second.mp4');
media.play();
$("ul li span").removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");
});

$("ul li span#third").click(function () {
media.pause();
media.setSrc('uploads/media/video/third.mp4');
media.play();
$("ul li span").removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");
});

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: So the `.setSrc()` call is failing? which library does MediaElementPlayer come from?

Comment: Yes, it fails the .setSrc() call.
I'm using this: http://mediaelementjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a "load" event after changing the video connection

Comment: media.setSrc("");
                                        media.load();
                                        media.play();

Comment: Plus a judge whether the current link is in front, if it is to update the link, reload, auto play

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether it is a timing issue on Android. I've never used that library, but poking around Google, it looks like some people have had issues with `setSrc` which apparently disappeared if you wait a few seconds after calling `setSrc` before calling `play`.

https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/414

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to delay the playing but it doesn't fix the issue.    [tried: setTimeout(function() {media.play();}, 3000);]. I think it's an Android bug.